# Sending data over network via MicroController (Sparkfun Thing // ESP8266)

Tags: esp8266, sparkfun, networking

I'm getting frustrated and keep hitting a wall. My basic setup is I have an Apache server running on my Raspberry Pi and I am looking to send sensor data over the wireless network both are connected to in order to post live data on the server. 
I've tested the server config and I'm able to stream random data from a WAMP server that is also on the network. So I think the server side is alright. 
Microcontroller side I have a Sparkfun Thing, it connects to the network and gets an IP address which I can ping. But I just can't seem to get it to send data properly.
Can anyone give me any advice on my code?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//Raspberry Pi Login Credentials.
const char WiFiSSID[] = "Alamo";
const char WiFiPSK[] = "12345678";

//Pin Definitions
const int LED_PIN = 5; 
const int ANALOG_PIN = A0;

//Variables
const char host[] = "192.168.44.1";


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ANALOG_PIN, INPUT);

  byte ledStatus = LOW;

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WiFiSSID, WiFiPSK);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    // Blink the LED
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus); // Write LED high/low
    ledStatus = (ledStatus == HIGH) ? LOW : HIGH;

    delay(100);
  }
}

void loop() 
{
//for testing purposes set temp to a default value.
//int temp = analogRead(ANALOG_PIN);
int temp = 43;

  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;

  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

String data = "temp1=" + (String)temp;
String url = "GET /data.php?" + data + " HTTP/1.1";

client.println(url);
  client.println("Host: 192.168.44.1");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
  client.flush();
  delay(500);

  //End of Send.  
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(100);

    while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
  client.stop(); //Stopping client
  //Deep sleep not necessary for testing
  //ESP.deepSleep(60U*60*1000000); //U for unsigned
  delay(100); //for above sleep
}
enter code here
```

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I don't see any code to transmit anything. You connect to the WiFi and then begin blinking an LED if the connection fails. What were you hoping for?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The data doesnt arrive?

Comment: The data sent never arrives to the PHP page. I've tested sending data from another computer on the network by running a php script that sends random numbers to the PHP page and that works. I'm not sure why the MCU script doesn't send. Even if I try something like,  String url = "GET /data.php?temp1=43 HTTP/1.1";
client.println(url); All I'm trying to do is send any data for variable temp1 to the php page data.php. I can also provide the php page code if that would be helpful.

Comment: All the communication is handled by the client.println and client.flush functions @transistor

Answer (score 1):

This code does infact work. What I found is happening is the Apache server is segregating data. So other users on the network can't see what my Microcontroller is sending, only it can see the data.

I was fortunate to be lead by a user from another forum to check the Apache access log. What I found was,

```
192.168.44.101 - - [02/Jan/2016:13:33:39 +0000] "GET /data.php?temp1=34 HTTP/1.1" 200 468 "-" "-"
192.168.44.101 - - [02/Jan/2016:13:33:39 +0000] "GET /data.php?temp1=34 HTTP/1.1" 200 468 "-" "-"
192.168.44.101 - - [02/Jan/2016:13:33:39 +0000] "GET /data.php?temp1=34 HTTP/1.1" 200 468 "-" "-"
```

Which means that my data is being received, but it is simply not view-able by the other clients on the network. Does anyone know the solution from here? How would I make the sent variable globally viewable to everyone connected?

Comment: Isn't this a PHP problem? If you can send and receive the data from the uC...

Comment: Correct. The data received by Apache isn't being loaded by the PHP script. You may need to ask a new question on Superuser.com or ServerFault.stackexchange.com with the related details, the server configuration and source for data.php. the electrical engineering part is done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will follow up on one of those boards.